# External files not included in webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to include normalise.css and moment (node modules) into my build by doing:

```
import moment from 'moment'
import styles from 'normalize'
```

however they are not included in the final build

config:

```
var config = {
  context: __dirname + '/client',
  entry: {
    main: [
      "./app.js"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "./public",
    filename: "dist.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!less"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: "style!css"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Comment: I made a seed that works very fine as expected with moment and normailze.css , i also updated my answer. check both answer and the seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say  `import styles from 'normalize'` it's accepting that you normalize is exporting something call styles.

### correct way is

`import 'normalize'`

Same with the moment make sure that it's exporting something otherwise if you fish to just include it in your project you can just do a simple import like

`import 'moment'`

Or

```
require('momentjs/moment.js')
```

> however they are not included in the final build
>   You should have got error when webpack could't find the modules you were importing

There is also a webpack plugin available for moment.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\\\/]locale$/, /^\.\/(en|ko|ja|zh-cn)$/)
]
```

[Source](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1435)

### Update:-

I made a simple [project on bitbucket with working moment and normalize included in build](https://bitbucket.org/jorawarsingh/es6-external-files)

Here is a little info if you want to use import.
For getting css file like normalize from node_modules you need to configure your webpack to resolve it

```
resolve:{
  extensions: ["",  ".js",".css"]
}
```

and then you can use simply import them like this

```
import moment from "moment";
import "normalize.css";
```

in the seed i mentioned you can clone and run npm on that and when every dependency is installed just run `npm start` and go to localhost:8080 now if you open dev tools you can se one app.js have moment built inside that and one app.css having normalize init.

Comment: Thx, but using import 'normalize' or import 'moment' had no effect, they are not in the final build

Comment: Are you getting any error? [Link to my seed](https://github.com/jorawarsingh/angular2-webpack-seed)

Comment: Now that's weird, when you say final build you mean products mode? Are they included in development? So you have repo on github?

Comment: I mean in any mode (dev or prod), unfortunately this is in a private repo

Comment: it's really hard to see like this what can be the reason. [take a look at this seed](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed) may be it can help. it do import for css like bootstrap.css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121259/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-superuberduper).

Answer (score 0):

Could try using ExtractTextPlugin. I have a Webpack 2 example below.  Here is the Webpack 1 [example](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/webpack-1/README.md).

```js
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

var config = {
  context: __dirname + '/client',
  entry: {
    main: [
      "./app.js"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "./public",
    filename: "dist.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
        ]
      },
      // can also try removing the ?query from css below
      {
        test: /(\.less|\.css)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
          loader: [
            'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
            'less'
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'styles.css' })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I moved to webpack 2, that fixed it.